# How to prevent drop on a particular node in Antd tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Antd tree for my React application. I am using drag and drop feature of the tree. I have this requirement where I should prevent user from dropping the dragged nodes on certain nodes. Is there any `droppable='false'` kind of config available on tree node to prevent the drop on the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allowDrop` property should be a function,
its parameter is node and its output is Boolean: `({ dropNode, dropPosition }) => boolean`
this function executes for each node of your tree and base on output the node will be dropable or not.

```js
allowDrop = {(node, dropPosition) => {
  console.log(node, dropPosition);
  //add some funtionality
  return false; //return true/false base on funtionality
}}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to prevent some nodes from becoming drop tagets. Meaning on these nodes one should not be able to drop other nodes. Hope I am clear on the requirement